# Using Boostrap 4 in an Angular 11 project

Tags: angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Boostrap 4 in an Angulat 11 project.

In my `asests/styles.scss` I've added

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

and in my `angular.json` I've added

```
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

Now I'm trying to make a dropdown in the nav bar

```
  <ul *ngIf="isAuthenticated" class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills nav-fill">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" title="Manage system.">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href='target="_self"'>><i class="fas fa-tools"></i> System</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/system"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i> System summary</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/system/users"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Users</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/system/groups"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> API Groups</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/system/roles"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> API Roles</a></li>
      </ul>
```

However, when I click the nav item the dropdown does not appear and indstead the browser navigates to `/`. Is it possible to get Boostrap to work with Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to use Boostrap and Angular at the same time. But personnaly, I prefer to use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) which is designed for Angular system.

Ng-bootstrap isn't using the last version of bootstrap but a lot of content is available and it's easier to install.